# Double integral - Matlab

Tags: matlab, integral

Trying to find double integral of that function:
[image]

Matlab code:

```
x = -1:0.05:1;
y = 0:0.05:1;
[x,y] = meshgrid(x);
F = sqrt((x).^2.*y) * ((sin((x).^2 .* (y).^2)).^3) - ((cos((x).^3.*(y).^3)).^5);
surfl(x,y,F);
colormap summer;
shading interp;
dblquad('sqrt((x).^2.*y) * (sin((x).^2 .* (y).^2)).^3 - (cos((x).^3.*(y).^3)).^5', -1, 1, 0, 1)
```

Errors:

> Untitled
>   Error using surf (line 57)
>   X, Y, Z, and C cannot be complex.
>
> Error in surfl (line 129)
>     h = surf(cax,x,y,z);
>
> Error in Untitled (line 5)
>   surfl(x,y,F);

How can I solve these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(x);
```

You are basically doing:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(x, x);
```

So basically `x` and `y` both go from `-1` to `1` and since the equation has a `sqrt(x.^2 .* y)`, you will get complex numbers. To generate a mesh using x, y with the bounds you specified for `x,y` use:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(x, y);
```